# Why isn’t data passed to the view in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, woocommerce, e-commerce

Data is not shown in the view page. The view page is loaded, but the data isn’t passed.

As my first Laravel project, I could not find out the error? If anyone helps to sort it out it would be a great help.

CartController.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;

class CartController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
         $product = Product::get();
         return view ('cart')->with(compact('products'));
         
     }
           
    public function show($id)
    {
        $product = Product::find($id);
       
        return view('cart')->with(compact('product'));
   }
}
```

cart.blade.php

```
@foreach($product as $p) 
    <tr class="">                                     
        <td class="d-none d-md-table-cell">
            <a href="#"><img class="img-fluid max-width-100 p-1 border border-color-1" src="{{asset('/storage/admin/'.$p ['prod_image_path'] ) }}" alt="Image Description"></a>
        </td>
        
        <td data-title="Product">
            <a href="#" class="text-gray-90">{{ $p ['prod_name'] }}</a>
        </td>
       
        <td data-title="Price">
            <span class="">LKR {{ $p ['prod_price'] }}.00</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/cart', 'CartController@index')->name('cart');
Route::get('/cart/{id}', 'CartController@show')->name('cart');
```

Comment: `$product` is a single instance of your `Product` model (or `null`); why are you calling `@foreach($product as $p) `? You'd just access each property like `$product->prod_price`. Edit: Oh wait; you're doing both... In one call, your passing a `Collection` or Products, but another, you're only passing 1. That's your issue there.

Comment: Your view can only have one model. It can either be a single item, or a list of item. A list would make more sense in your case (since that would still also support the scenario where there's only one item in the cart)

Comment: Would be `{{ $p->prod_name }}` instead of `{{ $p ['prod_name'] }}`

Comment: @sta what is the difference between those?

Comment: @Zeenath You can't access arrays this way `$data['name']`, and `$data->name` that only applies to objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your index method, your variable is named `$product` (singular), but you're sending `products` (plural) to your view. This will therefore be `null` in your view. Correct that spelling error and your index should be fine.

For your show method, @TimLevis already pointed out that you're retrieving a single instance of `Product` and not a collection.

Comment: I need to add cart functionality to this. What is the best practice to do that installing it or coding it? Please guide me.

Comment: This is way too complex for a comment. There are good tutorials out there (I'd recommend laracast if you keep doing laravel) and if you need help with a specific problem, ask another question :)

Answer (score 1):

```
return view('products', compact('product'));
```

You can't iterate over a single object unless there are array properties.
You can access your data in view like this {{$product->price}}